# javascript for loop for json variables in localStorage only displays last item in wtform

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage, wtforms

I'm trying to populate a wtform textareafield with items from a json array stored in localStorage. There should be 1 value on each line like this:

value1

value2

value3

when I get the items with my for loop only the last item is displayed.

value3

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
 function getValue() {
    //sets requirements as a json array
      var myinputs = $("[id^=reqInput]").map(function(){
       return this.value;
        }).get();
        localStorage.setItem("reqs", JSON.stringify(myinputs));
        console.log(myinputs);
    // calls arrays and populates criteria form
        for (var i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
          var reqArray = myinputs[i];
          console.log(reqArray);
          document.getElementById("mission").value = reqArray;
      };
    };
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("mission").value = reqArray;` Looks like you're overwriting it on each iteration, did you mean to concatenate instead?

Comment: Not on purpose. I just want to retrieve each value so it will be on separate lines.

Comment: The problem is more like you are outputting it wrong. For loop and referencing the same element, and replacing the value of it on every iteration with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following adjustments based of feedback from Noval Agung Prayogo and it works perfectly!

```
function getValue() {
//sets requirements as a json array
  var myinputs = $("[id^=reqInput]").map(function(){
   return this.value;
    }).get();
    sessionStorage.setItem("reqs", JSON.stringify(myinputs));
    console.log(myinputs);
    document.getElementById("mission").value = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
    var reqArray = myinputs[i];
    document.getElementById("mission").value += reqArray + '\n';
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the statement below will always replace the previous value with the new one on each loop:

```
document.getElementById("mission").value = reqArray;
```

If you want each value to be printed in separates line, you need to append the value on the `#mission` (not replacing it), and put `<br />` in between.

Example:

```
// empty the element at first
document.getElementById("mission").innerHTML = ""

for (var i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
    var reqArray = myinputs[i];
    document.getElementById("mission").innerHTML += reqArray + "<br />";
};
```